# Деление строки и запись в динамический массив

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Начал изучать `ArrayList` и столкнулся с одной неприятной вещью, деление строки при помощи делителя и дальнейшего помещения в массив с `ArrayList` не прокатывает. И мой код не работает:

```
ArrayList<String> infoListText = new ArrayList<>();
String msg = "First#Second"
String deltimetr = "#";
infoListText = msg.split(deltimetr);
```

Как реализовать подобное с `ArrayList`?

Comment: `infoListText.addAll(Arrays.asList(msg.split(deltimetr)));`

Answer (score 1):

```java
ArrayList<String> infoListText = new ArrayList<>();
String msg = "First#Second";
String deltimetr = "#";
Arrays.stream(msg.split(deltimetr)).forEach(word -> infoListText.add(word));
```

и проверить:

```java
infoListText.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
ArrayList<String> infoListText = new ArrayList<>();
String msg = "First#Second";
String deltimetr = "#";

String[] arr = msg.split(deltimetr);
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
infoListText.addAll(list);

System.out.println(infoListText); // [First, Second]
```

Или можно проще:

```java
String msg = "First#Second";
String deltimetr = "#";

ArrayList<String> infoListText =
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(msg.split(deltimetr)));

System.out.println(infoListText); // [First, Second]
```